# React : print paper size issue

Tags: reactjs, printing

We have found an issue with sales receipt print, which should accommodate its content to desired paper size, here that is (width 88mm, height: 279mm).
But in any paper size we choose from print preview window, it doesnt change its content , and hence we see detail text in very small size.
Visual representation of data needs to be fixed for dynamic paper size

ZoomIn image
[image]

Currently our angular application takes proper content representation for different paper size, angular is using typescripts HTMLIFrameElement interface
snapshot of angular print which should be the reference

[image]

**Solutions we tried as below:**

- Using pageStyle props of https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print
- Creating print without using react-to-print with the help of  https://dawsonwalker.me/blog/printing-page-hack and using styles
- Changing print component styles

Can we use HTMLIFrameElement interface in react component print, if yes, how?

Comment: You have an Angular application, but you're using a React library?

Comment: Thanks TJ for your reply. We are revamping the full application using React and 1st one was developed in Angular

Comment: why not use pdf format for the receipt. Modern browsers do support pdf files on the browser tab and it can cater to different paper size ?